# VHDL - Don't care ('-') value in the matching select/case statement expression

Tags: vhdl

I seem to be finding all the issues with VHDL lately.  I just had a problem where using a CASE? statement complained that I was using the "don't care" value in the case values "00010---".  I think that turned out to be a false report.  The real issue was it didn't like the underline characters I was using to mark position within the string... I think.

When I tried removing the underscores, I got a new error in code that has been working for weeks with no complaint.

```
function InTimeWindow (Count : natural) return boolean is
  begin
    return  (now > (Count * Hold_Period * 1 ms)) AND
            (now < ((Count + 1) * Hold_Period * 1 ms));
  end function InTimeWindow;
```

```
Error: COMP96_0392: TestBench/Alarm_top_TB.vhd : (310, 12): Cannot call impure subprogram from inside pure function "InTimeWindow".
```

It appears to be pointing to "now".  That's an impure function???

Well, I tried replacing the constant "Hold_Period" and that didn't fix it, so I added a time signal to the parameter list to replace 'now' and that got rid of this error.  It's just so strange that it has been working... or maybe not.  I just remembered earlier today I updated the tools!  I wonder if my other issue with the left hand side aggregate is gone now?  I'll have to try that later.

Meanwhile my original problem is back.

```
KERNEL: Fatal Error: Don't care ('-') value in the matching select/case statement expression.
```

in this code

```
case? Command is
  when 9x"000" =>
    assert false report Right_Left & " - NOP with enable detected";
  when 9x"001" =>
    assert false report Right_Left & " - Clear Display command";
  when 9x"002" =>
    assert false report Right_Left & " - Return Home command";
  when b"0000001--" =>
...
```

This has to be a bug in the tool, right?  The whole point of the '-' in the vector for the case? is to allow the use of the '-'.

Oh yeah, the underscore turned out to be a red herring.  This is with Active-HDL by Aldec.  I'm downloading the Intel tools and will be giving Modelsim a shot tomorrow.

Here is the complete procedure:

```
procedure Cmnd_Parse (
    Command     : in unsigned(8 downto 0);
    Right_Left  : in String;
    Cmnd_Time   : in time ) is
begin
    case? Command is
      when 9x"000" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - NOP with enable detected";
      when 9x"001" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - Clear Display command";
      when 9x"002" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - Return Home command";

      when b"0000001--" =>
        report Right_Left & " - Entry Mode Set command - I/D = " &
          std_logic'image(Command(1)) & ", SH = " &
          std_logic'image(Command(0)) severity warning;
        assert Command(1 downto 0) = "10"
          report "Entry Mode Set command invalid";
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - Entry Mode - command time insufficient";

      when b"000001---" =>
        report Right_Left & " - Display ON/OFF command - Display " &
          On_Off_Cont'image(On_Off_Cont'Val(
            sl2int(Command(2)))) & ", Cursor " &
          On_Off_Cont'image(On_Off_Cont'Val(
            sl2int(Command(1)))) & ", Cursor Blink " &
          On_Off_Cont'image(On_Off_Cont'Val(sl2int(Command(0))))
           severity warning;
        assert Command(2 downto 0) = "100"
          report "Function Set command invalid";
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - Display command - time insufficient";

      when b"00001----" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - Shift command - " &
          Disp_Cur_Cont'image(Disp_Cur_Cont'Val(
            sl2int(Command(3)))) & " shift " &
          Right_Left_Cont'image(Right_Left_Cont'Val(
            sl2int(Command(2)))) severity warning;
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - Shift command - time insufficient";

      when b"0001-----" =>
        report Right_Left & " - Function set command - " &
          integer'image(4 + 4 * sl2int(Command(4))) & " bit bus, " &
          integer'image(1 + 1 * sl2int(Command(3))) & " lines, 5x" &
          integer'image(8 + 2 * sl2int(Command(2))) & " char"
           severity warning;
        assert Command(4 downto 2) = "110"
          report "Function Set command invalid";
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - Function set - command time insufficient";

      when b"001------" =>
        report Right_Left & " - CGRAM set addr command - " &
          to_hstring(Command(5 downto 0)) severity warning;
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - CGRAM set addr - command time insufficient";

      when b"01-------" =>
        report Right_Left & " - DDRAM set addr command - " &
          to_hstring(Command(6 downto 0)) severity warning;
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - DDRAM set addr - command time insufficient";

      when b"1--------" =>
        report Right_Left & " - DATA write - " &
          to_hstring(Command(7 downto 0)) severity warning;
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - DDRAM set addr - command time insufficient";
      when others => null;
    end case?;
end procedure Cmnd_Parse;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Now` is obviously an impure function.

One characteristic of a pure function is that the output depends ONLY on the input arguments : the importance of which is that it can be optimised : e.g. computed ONCE and only recomputed if the args change (which, with a parameterless function, they don't). That clearly won't give the desired result for `Now`.

You can add `impure` before `function InTimeWindow` in the declaration : then calling `Now` would be allowed. (There may then be restrictions on calling the now `InTimeWindow` but deal with those as they arise. Unless you call it within another pure function, I don't anticipate any)

Having got a bigger incomplete fragment, the rest of the question does look like an issue with incorrectly implemented "matching case" operator.

Matching case is one of the freakier bits of syntactic sugar that got thrown into VHDL-2008 : it allows a pretty clean notation for certain cases, but some tools appear not to have implemented it yet. Frankly I can imagine it'll be a bitch to consistently generate correct code for.

GHDL hasn't : it's [on the ToDo list for the next major release](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/717) but Tristan is a busy guy!

Vivado (2018.2) fails at elaboration:

> [VRFC 10-1760] matching case selector expression contains meta value '-' ["/home/brian/Projects/ghdl/play/vivado/play/play.srcs/sources_1/imports/play/tester.vhd":19]

And you've seen how Aldec are doing with Active-HDL. (This is def worth reporting ).

That's 3 for 3 so far... Good luck with Modelsim!

It's good to push the compilers, and report defects - that's how they improve. But at some point you have to make progress. And in this case, now is probably the time; you'll (most likely) only face the same issues again at synth time.

Fortunately in your usage of matching case, this is very easy, because by good design, your usage consists of contiguous numeric ranges; something good old-fashioned VHDL handles reliably and compactly.
The following small testcase should compile and run on any simulator.

It converts to integer because ranges must be discrete types (not arrays). But you can give names to ranges, as the example illustrates, so you can hide the actual integer ugliness and keep the code clean.

```
entity tester is
end tester;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture test of tester is

constant Command_Cyc : time := 1 us;

subtype Display_Commands is natural range 8 to 15;

procedure Cmnd_Parse (
    Command     : in unsigned(8 downto 0);
    Right_Left  : in String;
    Cmnd_Time   : in time ) is
begin
    case to_integer(Command) is
      when 0 => --9x"000" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - NOP with enable detected";
      when 1 => --9x"001" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - Clear Display command";
      when 2 => -- 9x"002" =>
        assert false report Right_Left & " - Return Home command";

      --when "0000001--" =>
      --when "000000100" to "000000111" =>
      when 4 to 7 =>
        report Right_Left & " - Entry Mode Set command - I/D = " &
          std_logic'image(Command(1)) & ", SH = " &
          std_logic'image(Command(0)) severity warning;
        assert Command(1 downto 0) = "10"
          report "Entry Mode Set command invalid";
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - Entry Mode - command time insufficient";
          
      when Display_Commands =>
        report Right_Left & " - Display ON/OFF command - Display " 
           severity warning;
        assert Command(2 downto 0) = "100"
          report "Function Set command invalid";
        assert (Cmnd_Time + Command_Cyc <= now)
          report Right_Left & " - Display command - time insufficient";

      when others => null;
    end case;
end procedure Cmnd_Parse;

begin

exercise : process  is
begin
   wait for 10 ns;
   Cmnd_Parse("000000001", "L", 10 ns);
   wait for 100 ns;
   Cmnd_Parse("100000001", "R", 10 ns);
   wait for 100 ns;
   Cmnd_Parse("000000100", "R", 10 ns);
   
   wait for 100 ns;
   Cmnd_Parse("0000001--", "R", 10 ns);
   std.env.stop;

end process;

end architecture test;
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean "confuse" characters.  They are as in the quoted code.  It would seem Command is a 9 bit vector, in this case unsigned.  Right_Left is a string passed in to the procedure to print at he start of each report.   I have to say the whole pure/impure procedure is a new idea to me or I forgot it 100% if I learned it before.  I guess it has value of some sort.  I think the underscore is a red herring.  I took out all the underscores in the case statement parts and still get the above error like the "don't care" is not supported in case?, but that's what it's about, no?

Comment: Oh now I see a note saying the first para about underscores was a red herring. Thanks for posting a more substantial, even if still incomplete fragment. It would be much easier to help if you posted proper testcases.

Comment: Yeah, well I wasn't expecting to need test cases.  I guess I'm never certain about my use of the language... it is rather complex after all.  So I was asking in case I was mucking it up. -- A "work around" is actually much simpler than you offer.  Can't show multi-line code properly in a comment, but look at the selections in reverse order.  `IF (CMD(8)) THEN... ELSIF (CMD(7)) THEN ... ELSIF (CMD(6)) THEN ...`   The command structure was set up this way deliberately to simplify decoding I expect.  This is a model of an LCD controller chip in the test bench for the driver software.

Comment: That workround is fair enough (and makes the intent clearer IMO) : I was just doing minimal damage to the supplied example.